# Static vs. Dynamic class function (method) - which is faster?

Tags: php, performance, optimization

Has anyone done a proper benchmark on the difference in performance between these three foo functions?

```
function foo_global() {
}

class SomeClass {
  public function foo_dynamic() {
  }

  public static function foo_static() {
  }
}
```

To what I know global is fastest and dynamic slowest but I'd appreciate some more learned results.

Thanks

Comment: You should use them for their different purposes, not which is *fastest*.

Comment: I certainly hope this is academic curiosity...

Comment: It is interesting none the less, though the above are correct, you should design around readability first.  “Premature optimization is the root of all evil”

Comment: if there was a significant statistical difference, file a bug report.  I'm sure the difference pales in comparison to other factors such as Big O algorithm speed of the overall algorithm, not some piddly language syntax.

Comment: @DGM from my tests, function calls are pretty similar. However inlining short functions can offer substantial improvements. Which is the kind of information that can be gathered from tests like these.

Comment: To all those referring to design issues: thank you for your irrelevant input and waste of time. Even bigger thanks to those who voted down this question as if knowing an actual benchmark is a bad thing. Yes, of course I won't choose the design based on this answer BUT there's nothing wrong with a person wanting to know more details about his work environment, even if not solely for "academic curiosity". You might be surprised but there are some situations where extreme optimization over "piddly language syntax" becomes relevant. You should reconsider your fierce and unhelpful criticism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my tests the is virtually no difference:

[image: Function call benchmark]

So static calls are slightly slower than dynamic, and dynamic is slightly slower than global functions.

```
<?php
function pre_defined($v1, $v2) {
    return $v1 + $v2;
}
$anonymous = function($v1, $v2) {
    return $v1 + $v2;
};
$create_function = create_function('$v1, $v2', 'return $v1 + $v2;');

class StaticFunction {
    public static function test($v1, $v2) {
        return $v1 + $v2;
    }
}

class DynamicFunction {
    public function test($v1, $v2) {
        return $v1 + $v2;
    }
}
$dynamic = new DynamicFunction();

$v1 = 1;
$v2 = 2;
$iterations = 1000;
Performance\BenchmarkManager::add_group('Function call', new Performance\BenchmarkGroup(array(
    'benchmarks' => array(
        'empty loop' => function() use($iterations, $v1, $v2) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) {
            }
        },
        'native reference point' => function() use($iterations, $v1, $v2) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) {
                $result = $v1 + $v2;
            }
        },
        'pre defined' => function() use($iterations, $v1, $v2) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) {
                $result = pre_defined($v1, $v2);
            }
        },
        'anonymous' => function() use($iterations, $v1, $v2, $anonymous) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) {
                $anonymous($v1, $v2);
            }
        },
        'create_function' => function() use($iterations, $v1, $v2, $create_function) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) {
                $create_function($v1, $v2);
            }
        },
        'eval' => function() use($iterations, $v1, $v2) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) {
                eval('$result = $v1 + $v2;');
            }
        },
        'static' => function() use($iterations, $v1, $v2) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) {
                StaticFunction::test($v1, $v2);
            }
        },
        'dynamic' => function() use($iterations, $v1, $v2, $dynamic) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) {
                $dynamic->test($v1, $v2);
            }
        },
    ),
)));
```

Comment: Mind linking to that `Performance` library? BTW, great answer!

Comment: @Phil sorry, it is one I have created, and is not yet ready for open source.

Comment: @DGM x is time, so each benchmark has been run 14 times. y is iterations, so each benchmark was run y times in 1 second. E.g. the static function got called about 256,000 times per second, over 14 seconds.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed test and graph. Very nice although it wasn't as intuitive to understand what the axis are. The static vs. dynamic doesn't seem "slightly slower" if you consider it in %.